# Facebook sdk get user details from facebook userid

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there any way to get facebook user details using user facebookId.
Suppose, i will provide my facebook id and another user facebookId. Then facebook API will return me that user's details including friend status with me.

More specifically, I am A. My facebook id is A12345. Another facebook user B. That person's facebook id is B12345. 
Now A will send request using `{"my_id":"A12345","other_user_id":"B12345"}`

Response will user B details with friend status between A and B. Here friend status may be : friend, pending,No Friend etc.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

yes u can ! the docs is here : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/friend-list/ 
And u can try api call here : https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=%7Bfriend-list-id%7D&version=v2.6